# store object in sql database using springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need to store object of type invoice in invoice_history table, but when I do it it's storing null
[image]

This is the **model**:

```
public class InvoiceHistory {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "updated_date")
    private Timestamp updatedDate;
    @Transient
    @Column(name = "invoice_info")
    private Invoice invoiceHistory;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id")
    private Invoice invoice;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    private Employee employee;
}
```

and when I remove `@Transient` annotation, it's cause an **error** that:

> Could not determine type for: com.example.invoices.model.Invoice, at
> table: invoice_history, for columns:
> [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(invoice_info)]

and this is my **controller**:

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public ResponseEntity<InvoiceHistory> addHistory(@RequestBody InvoiceHistoryDTO invoice) {
    try {
        InvoiceHistory newInvoice = invoiceHistoryService
                .saveInvoiceHistory(new InvoiceHistory(invoice.getUpdatedDate(), invoice.getInvoiceInfo(), invoice.getInvoiceInfo().getEmployee()));
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newInvoice, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Also i read aboy jsonb datatype and i create this in the table :

[image]

and i change the code like this:

```
@Column(name = "invoice_data")
@Type(type = "jsonb")
private Invoice invoiceHistory;
```

and i define type :

```
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "string-array", typeClass = StringArrayType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "int-array", typeClass = IntArrayType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "json", typeClass = JsonStringType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class)
})
```

this is no errors on it, but also no data added into database

how can i solve it ?

Comment: Well have you read the error? Apparently there is no column named `invoice_info` in your table. Or if it is, I doubt it is an `InvoiceHistory` type column but rather an id... Please add your table structure to your question and describe what you want to achieve (it looks like a self-reference).

Comment: there is, check the first img, i take screenshoot

Comment: There is no type `invoice` in a regular database, so either you have a custom datatype and need a custom usertype or the column is of a different type.

Comment: There's another table called invoice in the same database, i want to store an objects (json object) on it, store invoice object in invoice_history table

Comment: You need a custom usertype for that how else would hibernate/jpa know what to store (xml, json, binary data, ...). You need something like https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types,.

Comment: I updated the question, can u check it ?

Comment: You included the proper version of the library? You added the `@TypeDefs` to the `package-info.java` and not a class?

Comment: no, i call them as `import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef;
import org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDefs;` 

and i import in pom.xml 
  `<dependency>
   <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.1</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. The typedefs need to be on the `package-info.java` in the package your entities are in (or specify the full type class in the `@Type` instead of an alias).

Comment: why i need that ? there's another way to do it ? :\

Comment: You need what? You need to tell the type, you want to register an alias (`jsonb`) so you need some global way to register those aliasses. If not an alias use the full classname instead of `jsonb` in your `@Type`.